# Getting errors when trying to deploy Nextjs to Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I've been trying to deploy my next.js app to vercel but keep getting the following error. Everything works locally and even builds with no errors. Not sure where to look for the error locations? I know the api keys are correct so not sure where to look for the issue.

```
13:51:22.627    info  - Creating an optimized production build...
13:52:12.318    info  - Compiled successfully
13:52:12.319    info  - Collecting page data...
13:52:12.653    (node:459) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
13:52:12.653    (node:459) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
13:52:12.653    > Build error occurred
13:52:12.655    [Error: Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.] {
13:52:12.656      type: 't',
13:52:12.656      code: 'auth/invalid-api-key',
13:52:12.656      a: null
13:52:12.656    }
13:52:12.710    error Command failed with exit code 1.
13:52:12.710    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
13:52:12.729    Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

Also if needed here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "next-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/webchannel-wrapper": "^0.5.1",
    "@monaco-editor/react": "^4.0.10",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.4.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.16.0",
    "codemirror": "^5.59.2",
    "firebase": "^8.6.3",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "monaco-editor": "^0.25.2",
    "next": "^11.0.1",
    "next-stripe": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "prismjs": "^1.24.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-codemirror2": "^7.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^2.2.0",
    "react-hotkeys-hook": "^3.1.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.12.1",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^6.10.0",
    "stripe": "^8.161.0",
    "swr": "^0.5.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.14",
    "typescript": "^4.3.4"
  },
  "browser": {
    "child_process": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you have a couple of different issues. #1 your api key isn't correct. My guess is you put it in .env-local and forgot to realize that git ignores those files, so you have to specify those as env vars on Vercel. Secondly, you have unhandled errors in async functions. You can do a `try{} catch{}` block, or you can do `.then().catch()` to handle the errors in the async functions. Let me know if you've set your api key in vercel. :)

Comment: Yup turns out it was the .env causing the error. I've added them in vercel and everything works great now!

Comment: @StackUnderFlow Feel free to add the solution you found as an answer to your own question. This indicates the question already has an answer.